# Printing the wrong variable altough checked the variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I really having trouble with my 'c' variable and I don't know why... I checked by putting a print(c) right after it is defined and it gave me a different output from the final one... Can someone help me please?

```
###Soccer Championship###
#Functions#
def fatorial(n):
    fat = 1
    x = 1
    while x <= n:
        fat *= x
        x += 1
    return fat
#First Variables#
number_of_teams=int(input("How many teams are in the championship?"))
counter=0
list_game_results=[]
team_points_dic={}
team_victories_dic={}
team_goal_difference_dic={}
team_goals_pro_dic={}
result_points={}
result_victories={}
result_goal_difference={}
result_goal_pro={}
i=0
#Game Result Entries#
while(counter<((fatorial(number_of_teams))/fatorial(number_of_teams-2))):
    game_result=str(input("Type game result:"))
    print("Working")  #TIRAR#
    counter+=1
    list_game_results.append(game_result)
print(list_game_results)  #TIRAR#
#Adding Teams to Dictionaries#
counter=0
while(counter<((fatorial(number_of_teams))/fatorial(number_of_teams-2))):
    Team1=list_game_results[i].split()
    if(not Team1[0] in team_points_dic):
        team_points_dic[Team1[0]]=0
        counter+=1
        i+=1
        print("Working", team_points_dic)  #TIRAR#
    else:
        counter+=1
        i+=1
counter=0
i=0
while(counter<((fatorial(number_of_teams))/fatorial(number_of_teams-2))):
    Team1=list_game_results[i].split()
    if(not Team1[0] in team_victories_dic):
        team_victories_dic[Team1[0]]=0
        counter+=1
        i+=1
        print("Working1", team_victories_dic)  #TIRAR#
    else:
        counter+=1
        i+=1
counter=0
i=0
while(counter<((fatorial(number_of_teams))/fatorial(number_of_teams-2))):
    Team1=list_game_results[i].split()
    if(not Team1[0] in team_goal_difference_dic):
        team_goal_difference_dic[Team1[0]]=0
        counter+=1
        i+=1
        print("Working2", team_goal_difference_dic)  #TIRAR#
    else:
        counter+=1
        i+=1
counter=0
i=0
while(counter<((fatorial(number_of_teams))/fatorial(number_of_teams-2))):
    Team1=list_game_results[i].split()
    if(not Team1[0] in team_goals_pro_dic):
        team_goals_pro_dic[Team1[0]]=0
        counter+=1
        i+=1
        print("Working3", team_goals_pro_dic) #TIRAR#
    else:
        counter+=1
        i+=1
#Counting Points and Victories#
counter=0
i=0
while(counter<((fatorial(number_of_teams))/fatorial(number_of_teams-2))):
    Team1=list_game_results[i].split()
    if(Team1[1]>Team1[4]):
        team_points_dic[Team1[0]]+=3
        team_victories_dic[Team1[0]]+=1
        print(team_points_dic, team_victories_dic)
        counter+=1
        i+=1
    elif(Team1[1]==Team1[4]):
        team_points_dic[Team1[0]]+=1
        team_points_dic[Team1[3]]+=1
        print(team_points_dic)
        counter+=1
        i+=1
    else:
        team_points_dic[Team1[3]]+=3
        team_victories_dic[Team1[3]]+=1
        print(team_points_dic, team_victories_dic )
        counter+=1
        i+=1
#Counting Goal Difference#
counter=0
i=0
while(counter<((fatorial(number_of_teams))/fatorial(number_of_teams-2))):
    Team1=list_game_results[i].split()
    team_goal_difference_dic[Team1[0]]+=(int(Team1[1])-int(Team1[4]))
    team_goals_pro_dic[Team1[0]]+=int(Team1[1])
    team_goal_difference_dic[Team1[3]]+=(int(Team1[4])-int(Team1[1]))
    team_goals_pro_dic[Team1[3]]+=int(Team1[4])
    print(team_goal_difference_dic, team_goals_pro_dic)
    counter+=1
    i+=1
#Sorting Alphabetically#
for t in sorted(team_points_dic):
    print(t, team_points_dic[t], team_victories_dic[t], team_goal_difference_dic[t], team_goals_pro_dic[t])
#Evaluating Champion#
for value in team_points_dic:
    if team_points_dic[value] in result_points:
        result_points[team_points_dic[value]].append(value)
    else:
        result_points[team_points_dic[value]]=[value]
for value in team_victories_dic:
    if team_victories_dic[value] in result_victories:
        result_victories[team_victories_dic[value]].append(value)
    else:
        result_victories[team_victories_dic[value]]=[value]
for value in team_goal_difference_dic:
    if team_goal_difference_dic[value] in result_goal_difference:
        result_goal_difference[team_goal_difference_dic[value]].append(value)
    else:
        result_goal_difference[team_goal_difference_dic[value]]=[value]
for value in team_goals_pro_dic:
    if team_goals_pro_dic[value] in result_goal_pro:
        result_goal_pro[team_goals_pro_dic[value]].append(value)
    else:
        result_goal_pro[team_goals_pro_dic[value]]=[value]
a=str(sorted(result_points.values())[0])
a=a.replace("'", "")
a=a.replace("[", "")
a=a.replace("]", "")
b=str(sorted(result_victories.values())[0])
b=b.replace("'", "")
b=b.replace("[", "")
b=b.replace("]", "")
lenght=len(result_goal_difference)
c=str((sorted(result_goal_difference.values())[lenght-1]))
**print(c)**
c=c.replace("'", "")
c=c.replace("[", "")
c=c.replace("]", "")
d=str(sorted(result_goal_pro.values())[0])
d=d.replace("'","")
d=d.replace("[", "")
d=d.replace("]", "")
print(d)
if(len(a)==1):
    print("Vencedor:", a)
elif(len(b)==1):
    print("Vencedor:", b)
elif(len(c)==1):
    **print("Vencedor:", c)**
else:
    print("Vencedor:", d)
```

Both 'c's I marked down with asterisks are printing differently... My input is:

2

Araguaia 2 x Cascavel 1

Cascavel 3 x Araguaia 0

Comment: Try creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @PatrickArtner the error must be in the final part! from the **print(c)** to the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you print c its of type string:

```
['Cascavel']
```

Then you remove the brackets and single quotes from that string:

```
Cascavel
```

Then you print c on the condition that it has length == 1.

I think you might believe that c is a list from the first print, but it's not. Try to also `print(type(c))`. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Why do you have brackets and single quotes in that string?

Comment: This is correct. I'm not sure why you are measuring the len at the end there at all.